# Getting all HEX values from image using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I got an idea but im not sure it will work.

Is there anyway, using PHP or Javascript, to list ALL the HEX values on each pixel of a image?
The thing i want to do is get the HEX code for the most used color in that image.

So for example i got a 4x4 image. Two of them is #000000 and third is #c1c1c1 and fourth is #FFFFFF
Then it list them as:

```
#000000
#000000
#c1c1c1
#FFFFFF
```

and with that i can code something to say like:

```
Most color used: #000000
```

Is there anyway to do this, is it too complicated?

Comment: maybe you can do this somehow like this: http://donatstudios.com/Damn-Simple-PHP-ASCII-Art-Generator or you can ask here to: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/ocr-with-php-515427.html 
please share the result, i am really curious :)

Comment: Thanks. Im gonna try to work with that script and transform it. I'll answer if i manage to do it. :)

Comment: please inform us about the status of this project

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do this using [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/imagecolorat). For JavaScript using canvas it will be [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29)

Comment: Im gonna look into those functions. Thanks! :)